# How to customise the UIImagePicker editing view?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to customise the default UIImagePicker editing view with my own design. I have used the following code to create the image picker.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
  imagePicker.delegate = self;
  imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  imagePicker.allowsEditing = TRUE;
  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will show me the default camera view and once I take a picture, it will navigate to the default editing screen with 'Retake' and 'Choose' buttons. I need to replace this screen with my own design. Is there is any possible way for achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom view controller and overlay it to the default pickerViewController.

Here is an example code from one of my projects:

```
- (BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withAnimation:(BOOL)animated {
   if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) {
       ShowErrorMessage(nil, @"Your device doesn't support camera.");
       return NO;
   }

   CameraOverlayViewController *cameraOverlay = [controller.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:FuCameraOverlayID];
   cameraOverlay.delegate = self;
   self.cameraOverlay = cameraOverlay;
   UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
   cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
   cameraUI.delegate = self;
   [cameraUI setCameraOverlayView:self.cameraOverlay.view];
   self.imagePicker = cameraUI;

   [controller presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:animated completion:^{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
   }];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I think this will help me to customise my camera view. But I need to customise my image editing view(which comes once I take a picture from camera).